# Is there a name for a monounary algebra with an injective unary operation? Is there a research of these algebras.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

To put is short, a *unary algebra* is a universal algebra with several unary operations and a *monounary algebra* is a unary algebra with only one operation. I am interested in a special kind of monounary algebras - those whose sole operation $f$ is injective, i.e. it has the property for any $x$ and $y$, if
$f(x)= f(y)$, then $x = y$. Possibly, a term different from "injective" is customarily used.

Answer (score 2):

Such algebras are rather simple objects, and as such there isn't much to say about them. Specifically, an injective monounary algebra is determined up to isomorphism by a few cardinal invariants:

- How many cycles of size $n$ it has, for each finite $n$.
- How many "$\mathbb{Z}$-chains" it has.
- How many "maximal $\mathbb{N}$-chains" it has.

(A bit more precisely, if $\mathcal{A}$ is an injective monounary algebra with underlying set $A$ and function symbol $f$, let $\approx$ be the transitive symmetric closure of the relation $y=f(x)$. A cycle of size $n$ is an $\approx$-class of size $n$; a $\mathbb{Z}$-chain is an infinite $\approx$-class on which $f$ is a bijection; and a maximal $\mathbb{N}$-chain is an infinite $\approx$-class on which $f$ is not a bijection.)

Given this, I don't think they have been studied on their own.